# Concurrent Writes Mongo/Mongoose Create Duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In `nodejs` + `mongoose`, I have this schema and function:

```
var storeSchema = new Schema({      
    sensor_id:  {type: String, required: true},
    dateString:  {type: String, required:true},
    created:    {type: Date},
    values:     {}
});
  storeSchema.index({sensor_id:1,dateString:1},{unique:true});
// sensorId and stringDate come from outside
//
function(sensorId,stringDate)
{
   Store.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    sensor_id: sensorId, 
                    dateString:stringDate,                       
                }, 
                updated,
                {
                    new:false
                },
                function(err, sensorResult){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if (sensorResult === null)
                        {
                            var newRecord = {                                       
                                    sensor_id:sensorId,
                                    dateString:stringDate,
                                    created:new Date(),
                            };

                            Store.create(newRecord,function(err){
                            });                         
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            );
   }
```

My script simply checks if a record exists: If not, it creates a new record, otherwise updates the old one.
Data to be saved come from another script (basically a server).

A packet is a JSON object which contain `sensorId` and `stringDate`.
However, if I send two identical "packets" to the script, it stores two duplicated records, i.e. with the same dateString and sensorId.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query as follows solve the problem:

```
 Store.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    sensor_id: sensorId, 
                    dateString:stringDate,                       
                }, 
                updated,
                {
                    upsert:true
                },
                function(err, sensorResult){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    else

                }
            );
```